# Regex string to find numbers not starting with one of several numbers

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking to find 15 or 16 digit numbers that don't start with certain numbers.  So I have:

```
  [0-9]{15,16}
```

and that gets me my 15 and 16 digit numbers but I don't want the numbers if they start with 596542 or 751302. So I tried:

```
     ^(?!596542|751302)[0-9]{15,16}
```

But that didn't work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:  I want to find the numbers if (?!596542|751302) is not at the beginning of the expression - not the beginning of the line.  Also, it may be in a longer string of numbers.

Comment: Use `\b(?!596542|751302)[0-9]{15,16}\b`

Comment: Why did you add the `^` anchor?  That will force it to only match if the numbers are at the beginning of a line.

Comment: I want to match only if the numbers are at the beginning of the line

Comment: Then use `(?m)^(?!596542|751302)[0-9]{15,16}\b`

Comment: If spaces are accidentally placed in your code blocks please remove them otherwise you should know they have a meaning in a Regular Expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to match numbers with at least 15 digits that *do not contain* `596542` and `751302` use

```
@"\b(?![0-9]*(?:596542|751302))[0-9]{15,}"
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%28%3f!%5b0-9%5d*%28%3f%3a596542%7c751302%29%29%5b0-9%5d%7b15%2c%7d&i=ttt+12345678901234%0d%0aggg+123456789012345%0d%0agg+1234567890123456%0d%0a+gg+12345678901234567%0d%0a+gghh+123456759654245%0d%0aju+751302789012345&o=m)

If you need to match numbers with at least 15 digits that *do not start* with the 2 values, use

```
@"\b(?!596542|751302)[0-9]{15,}"
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%28%3f!596542%7c751302%29%5b0-9%5d%7b15%2c%7d&i=ttt+12345678901234%0d%0aggg+123456789012345%0d%0agg+1234567890123456%0d%0a+gg+12345678901234567%0d%0a+gghh+123456759654245%0d%0aju+751302789012345&o=m).

```
var results = Regex.Matches(s, @"\b(?![0-9]*(?:596542|751302))[0-9]{15,}")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Value)
    .ToList();
```

To match whole numbers, add `\b` at the end of the pattern.

Comment: I'm sorry I was originally unclear.  Yes - I want to match if it is at the beginning of the expression, not the beginning of the line as I originally said.  I am looking for the match anywhere in the line.  I couldn't get \b(?!596542|751302)[0-9]{15,16}\b to work in https://regex101.com/  with this sample data:  12345697890123451234567890132456790  It says NO MATCH but there is at least on 16 digit number in there.

Comment: Now, you say *at least* 15 digits? What are your criteria? Anyway, it seems all you need is `@"\b(?!\d*(?:596542|751302))[0-9]{15,}`. Please update the question with the  comprehensive test cases since your specs are not clear. I added two possible solutions - please check if they meet your requirements.

Comment: Thank you very much.  What I needed was this:  @"\b(?!596542|751302)[0-9]{15,16}"

Comment: So, only a *leading* word boundary.